# Array function issues

Tags: c++, arrays

I basically ask the user to enter the number of corners they want. Then ask them to enter the x,y co ordinates for the corners. I don't know how to do the array part so corner 1 comes up and they enter x and y then corner 2 and they enter x1,y1 and so on.. please help!! this is what I have.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int corners;
    int n;
    int mC;
int position;
int position1;
float perimeter;

{
    cout<<"Enter the number of corners";  // Get the amount of corners
    cin>>corners;

}
for(n=0;n>corners;n++) // get positions for each corner
```

Comment: What do you mean by "corner 1 comes up"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a vector of of pairs, this should be used to hold the corners.

At input you loop, n times, and each time, you create a temporary pair from cin, so you take 2 numbers and put it in the pair, at the end you just push_back the pair into vector.

At the end of the loop you should have a vector of coordinates.